# To get data from one table to another in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created new module name handmade t-shirt design management in magento. It has t-shirt-design & t-shirt designer. designers will add their design from admin panel. so wen they add t-shirt design, I need to select t-shirt designer using t-shirt designer table, in other words I need id of that designer and want to store it in t-shirt design. How can i do this in MAGENTO?

Please help
.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: How is this setup? Description & code would be useful as there is probably a multitude of ways going about doing this. How do the designers login to the admin, do they have their own account, if so, you could simply programatically assign the ID of the logged in designer to the T-Shirt when they upload in the admin, without them needing to select anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to the event

```
<catalog_product_prepare_save>
```

And in the Observer you can have the data Values

For example

```
public function saveProductBrand($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (isset($categoryIds)) {
        foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
            $isBrandCategory = Mage::getModel('brands/navigation')->isBrandCategory($categoryId);
            if ($isBrandCategory)
                $brandCategories[] = $categoryId;
        }
```

You can Just have a [look at HERE](http://pastebin.com/aTxsjwJ8)